# How to format the output so that they are all aligned in the .log file?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script for my college assignment that basically gathers your computer information and outputs it to a .log file. I've written the script already but when it outputs the information to the .log file, the Installed Software Names, Installed Software GUIDs, and the name of all users in the computer are listed like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Anyway I can edit my script to make it like this? Here's my script:

```
#Checking For Log File

$LogLocation = "$Home\Desktop\"
$LogFile = "Baabbasi.log"
$TestPathResult = Test-Path $Home\Desktop\Baabbasi.log
If ($TestPathResult -eq "False") {New-Item -Path $LogLocation -Name $LogFile -ItemType File}

#The Process After
Clear-Host 

$TodaysDate =  Get-Date

$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName 

$BiosName = Get-WMIObject Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$BiosVersion = Get-WMIObject Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version

$HDSizes = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" | Select-Object @{Name="size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f($_.size/1gb)}}
$TotalHDSize = ($HDSizes | Measure-Object "size(GB)" -Sum).Sum

$PhysicalMemory = (Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory).Capacity
$PhysicalMemoryinGB = $PhysicalMemory/1gb

$OSVersion = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Version
$OSName = $env:OS

$InstalledSoftwareNames = Get-WMIObject Win32_Product | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Out-String

$InstalledSoftwareGUID = Get-WMIObject Win32_Product | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber| Out-String

$LatestHotfix = Get-Hotfix | select-object HotFixID,InstalledOn | Sort-Object InstalledON -descending | Select -first 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HotfixID

$UserAccount = [Environment]::UserName

$AllUserAccounts = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Out-String

Add-Content $Home\Desktop\Baabbasi.log "
Date: $TodaysDate
======================================================================
Computer Name: $ComputerName
================ ====================================================== 
BIOS Name: $BiosName
BIOS Version: $BiosVersion
HD Size: $TotalHDSize GB
RAM Size: $PhysicalMemoryinGB GB
Operating System: $OSName
Operating System Version: $OSVersion
Installed Software Name: 
$InstalledSoftwareNames 
Installed Software GUID: 
$InstalledSoftwareGUID 
Last Installed Hot Fix: $LatestHotfix
Name of Registered System User: $UserAccount
Names of All Registered System Users on the System: 
$AlluserAccounts
========================================================================
========================================================================
"
```

Comment: Please include pictures as well as code with your question. It's quite annoying to have to go to several other places just to find out what it is that you actually want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the statement

```
$InstalledSoftwareGUID = Get-WMIObject Win32_Product |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber| Out-String
```

to something like this:

```
$InstalledSoftwareGUID = Get-WMIObject Win32_Product |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber |
    % { (' ' * 20) + $_ } | Out-String
```

That will prepend each GUID with 20 spaces (adjust the number to your desired indention depth) before converting the list to a single string.